# Check if post has gallery images/media

Tags: shortcode, gallery, media, conditional-tags

Is there a Wordpress conditional that I can use to check for gallery images/media in a post?

I do not want to check if the [gallery] shortcode exist in a post.

Attached is a screenshot of what I want to check for and if is images I want to output them to the page.

[image: Gallery has 4 image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No Need for SQL queries in the template.

```
function wpse_72594_get_attachments( $id, $mime = '' )
{
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_mime_type' => $mime,
        'post_parent' => $id
    ); 
    $attachments = get_posts($args);
    if ($attachments) 
        return $attachments;

    return false;
}
```

Then call the function like this *(300 is the post ID)*:

- `wpse_72594_get_attachments(300)`, grabs all attachments
- `wpse_72594_get_attachments(300, 'image' )`, only images
- `wpse_72594_get_attachments(300, 'application/pdf' )`, only pdf files